# "plot.new has not been called yet" error when graphing ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

Why does this happen/How can I troubleshoot this? Iv read some of the other entries about this error but am still confused, especially because when I run the following code without the bolded part, it runs fine, but with the bolded section included, i get this error.

Code:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 500) + 
axis(side = 1, at = seq(0, 20000, by = 500))
```

Error:

```
Error in axis(side = 1, at = seq(0, 20000, by = 500)) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

Answer (score 1):

`axis` is part of the graphics package not ggplot. So `axis` is looking for a `plot` not a `ggplot`.

Try

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 500) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,20000, by = 500))
```

Or in base graphics

```
hist(diamonds$price) 
axis(side = 1, at = seq(0, 20000, by = 500))
```